# Visual StudioTeam Services Online add login service during build

Tags: build, azure-devops

I am using [sinponia](https://github.com/rlidwka/sinopia) to host a private npm package and want to complete a publish on the build in [visual studio team services online](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-team-services-vs.aspx). However in order to publish i need to login . I have set the version number locally ( although i would like to do this as well in the build ) and then in the build i

```
npm set registry http://foobar.net:0000
npm publish
```

The error is straight forward. 
**npm publish requires login**

I am not sure how to pass my username and password though , or prompt the build to execute the `npm login` properly . When i do add `npm login` to the build the build stalls and then fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run npm adduser command to add the user to login, it will generate a ".npmrc" file in your user directory. Copy that file to your npm project src folder, npm publish should can finish successfully.

Comment: I have added that , I a bit confused as to the settings that i need to add. Do i need to get a **cert** or just add the **user** and **key**. And if i add that will those not be exposed in the source control.

Comment: What do you mean about get a cert of just add the user and key?

Comment: Sorry i did not properly read your answer. Thanks it fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using an On-Prem agent and not using the hosted agent. While not a perfect solution, you can set the user by calling [npm adduser](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/adduser) once manually on the build agent.